# How to hide the new action "Paste as Lines " in netbeans 8.2 platfrom

Tags: java, action, netbeans-8

I need to know the ID of the action "Paste as lines" in netbeans platform 8.2 to be able to hide it using the configuration file layer.xml

So my question is: what is the ID of this action ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here the ID of the "Paste as Lines" action

> org.netbeans.modules.editor.actions.PasteLinesAction

I used the following code to retrieve the action name :

```
 Arrays.asList(Repository.getDefault().getDefaultFileSystem().getRoot().getFileObject("Menu/Edit").getChildren()).
               forEach(child -> System.out.println(child.getName()));
```

then I updated the Layer.xml file to hide this action

```
  <folder name="Menu">
    <folder name="Edit">
        <file name="clipboard-lines.shadow_hidden"/>
    </folder>
 </folder>
```